# Como puedo arreglar el error 40 al conectar el servidor local en sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Este es el error que ne sale:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-1N1OK6F.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se
establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. 

No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. 
Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto 
y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. 

(provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una 
 conexión con SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Comment: desde donde estas intentando conectarte? es desde un desarrollo que realizas o usando el Sql Server Management Studio. El servicio de Sql server esta local en la misma pc o es remota?

Comment: Hola Miguel Bienvenido a SO en Español, como muy bien dice leandro, nos podrias dar mas datos para poder ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: Miguel llegaste a resolver tu problema?

Comment: Tienes que iniciar el servicio de SQL  en el panel de servicios de Windows, me pasa cada vez que instalo SQL que no se inicia automaticamente.   Intenta acceder desde SQL management primero... si tienes acceso desde allí entonces es otro problema con la aplicación.

Answer (score 6):

Estás tratando de conectarte usando el protocolo *Named Pipes* el cual se encuentra desactivado por defecto.

**Solución:**

1. Entra al *Sql Server Configuration Manager*
2. Expande *SQL Server Network Configuration*
3. Clic en *Protocols for MSSQLSERVER*
4. Clic derecho en *Named Pipes*
5. *Enable*
6. Reinicia el servicio

[image: Habilitar Named Pipes]

Answer (score 4):

Este error es muy común y muy fácil de solucionar: Solo tienes que activar los servicios "SQL Server" y "SQL Server" en el "Sql Server Configuration Manager". Te dejo unas fotos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero solucione tu problema.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Tener en cuenta de utilizar barra invertida en la cadena de conexion.

**Incorrecto:**

`var conexion = "Data Source=Maquina/instancia.."`;

**Correcto:**

```
var conexion = @"Data Source=Maquina\instancia..";
```