# Para conectar sql server con visual studio como hago necesito ayuda

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo hacer la conexión desde c# con ssql server para hacer consultas SQL
Gracias

Comment: El servicio de Sql Server esta en la pc local, o esta en una remota ? validaste que no se requiere especificar ninguna instancia?

Comment: en una pc local

Comment: sabes si usas Sql Server Express ? Si desplegas el combo de "Nombre de servidor" no te muestra los servicios que detecta

Comment: Puede validar que tu SQL este corriendo, si te puedes conectar con el SQL Management??

Comment: Yo quiero que me aprezacan las bases de datos en visual pero no es posible

Comment: Si es una pc local porque no defines (local), localhost o simplemente "." un punto en el campo "Nombre de servidor".   REcuerda validar si usaste Sql Express que no este instalado en alguna instancia

Comment: Puedes intentar una conexion en modo SQL en lugar de modo Windows ???

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como puedo arreglar el error 40 al conectar el servidor local en sql Server](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3072/como-puedo-arreglar-el-error-40-al-conectar-el-servidor-local-en-sql-server). Por favor revisa esta respuesta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/3356/20 si es que encuentras ahí la solución

Answer (score 2):

Si el motor de BD es local el servidor se llamara (local) como se adjunta en la imagen

[image: Conxión local a Sql Server]

Answer (score 0):

Copia el nombre completo de tu SQL Server, todo lo que esta seleccionado en la siguiente imagen con el formato:

NombreDeInstancia\SQLEXPRESS

[image: Copia el nombre completo]