# Error 40 en SQL server al querer conectar aplicacion - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, visual

Tengo un programa en c# Visual Studio 2022 y la base en SQL Server. Puedo añadir el origen de base de datos sin problemas, pero al ejecutar me sale error 40.

Verifique todo lo siguiente:
El servicio esta corriendo con normalidad.
El protocolo TCP/IP esta habilitado.
El firewall esta deshabilitado.
Hice un test con un archivo .udl y el mismo funciona OK.
Probe usar SQL con usuario local y de dominio, sin resultados.
Levante el mismo proyecto en otra computadora y da el mismo error.

En todos los lugares que estuve buscando informacion , no salia de esos puntos, sinceramente no se que mas puede ser el inconveniente. Algo mas que se me este escapando?

Saludos!

Comment: Estimado, podrias colocar el error completo en tu pregunta, no recuerdo cual es el error 40 ... sera este ["proveedor: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - No se pudo abrir una conexión"](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection). POdrias colocar tu "cadena de conexion" (para ver si va por IP o nombre servidor). Pero te puede servir de ayuda ["esta pregunta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3072/como-puedo-arreglar-el-error-40-al-conectar-el-servidor-local-en-sql-server)